# Facebook Api for retrieving the business invoices

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to retrieve business invoices using a curl command and testing this on Facebook Graph API Explorer. This is the query that I'm using

`<FB_Business_ID>/business_invoices?start_date=2019-06-01&end_date=2019-07-01`

The query is taken from this document
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/business-manager/get-started#invoice

I'm making this call using the 14.0 version, I also tried on 13.0 and 12.0, and I have all the necessary permission to create this call. Every time on making a call, I get a single data object

Comment: The example in the docs uses `start_date=2017-01-01&end_date=2017-04-01`, and is supposed to return three entries, for billing periods 2017-01-01, 2017-02-01 and 2017-03-01. So the end date appears to be exclusive.

Comment: even for the longer date range, I still get an empty data array. I searched this on the FB community and a lot of other folks have the same problem with no answer